# Determining if a div was clicked on its border

Tags: jquery

I'd like to implement a primitive eyedropper function, where an eyedropper cursor can be clicked on a div with a background color and this color pulled by reading the CSS style with jQuery. But what if the div's border is clicked and it's a different color?  How do I pull that color? I don't see anything in the click event that tells me that the border was clicked rather than the contents.

Is there a way to sense a border click, without going through all the math of calculating where the border is and if the click was in that area?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: well, if assumption is that there is diff color for div border and div content , then i guess both would have a diff css class , why dont you try extracting the class name when click event is triggered.based on class name you can decide the color

Comment: Why not use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z5mJ7/2/)?

Comment: dreamweiver: It seems like the div will have one class whether the border and content are the same color or not.

Comment: You can use offsetX and offsetY value to determine this. See http://jsfiddle.net/nKYuz/

Comment: Vucko: You're pulling the border and the content color from CSS but I still don't know which one applies because I don't which one I clicked.  Also, your border alert doesn't show the color for me.

Comment: jimy: offsetX and offsetY are undefined when I run the fiddle, but clientX and clientY are there and pageX and pageY are there.  These tell me the X and Y where the mouse was clicked but not if this is in the border or the content. I was hoping to avoid the box math of figuring out where in the div the click occurred.

Comment: @Steve I doubt there is any option from which we can get either the click was on border of the element. Calculation will have to do based on the border size. offsetX and offsetY is coming for me try this updated one with alert - http://jsfiddle.net/nKYuz/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Is there a way to sense a border click, **without going through all the math of calculating where the border is and if the click was in that area?***

**Short answer**: No, not without going through math calculations.

Reason is, borders aren't elements, they are part of the DOM element and do not have their own separate event handlers.

**But**, to achieve what you want, it seems like you'll need at least these ingredients:

`.offset()`, `.innerWidth()`, `innerHeight()`, the 4 border widths via `.css()`, `event.pageX()` and `event.pageY`

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/YvFQX/**

Familiarizing yourself with the box model will help a great deal in thought-processes like these, as well as developing a good code strategy.

**Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html**

Comment: Thanks for thinking this through, Terry.  The rest will be easy.